# Attempting to texture paint fills in large random portions?

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-painting, retopology

Im practicing modeling hands and I got to the point where I wanted to try to texture paint. However I ran into a strange issue where on certain sections of the mesh whenever I try to paint a small area it fills a random large chunk of the mesh with whatever color I'm attempting to use.

For example, I tried to paint a small section of the forearm but the second I pressed down on my pen pad the entire forearm got filled in with my selected color. The same thing happens when I use my mouse.

I find it strange because only certain random sections get filled in so I dont think its a fill issue. I was thinking it was an issue with the topology of the mesh so would it fix the issue if I retopologize the entire mesh?

I would greatly appreciate any help Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have uv's that are too small at these points.
Try to use correct seams before unwrapping or use lightmap uv.

Comment: @Yvain Huge help! Thank you sir!